# Xcode crashes on launch

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an Application for iOS and I changed nothing in the Application. But at a restart of my Mac, Xcode crashes every time.

Don't know if this is important, but my spotlight can't find any applications and  also when I open the finder and using the shortcut cmd + shift + H I see a white window.

Xcode isn't starting anymore and throws this error:

```
Process:               Xcode [1346]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.2 (9548)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9548000000000000~7
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       814662604
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1346]

Date/Time:             2015-12-24 11:01:44.753 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
Report Version:        11


Time Awake Since Boot: 4000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        4  Dispatch queue: DVTFilePathEventWatcher - event queue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000108a5a000-0000000108a5e000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7C68

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: DVTFilePath cache derivation lock for key DVTFilePathKey_SortedDirectoryContents
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8df27aa0 search_method_list(method_list_t const*, objc_selector*) + 2
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8df28d76 lookUpImpOrForward + 413
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8df22591 objc_msgSend + 209
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000108a741f8 -[DVTFileSystemVNode addCachedEntriesFromDictionary:] + 215
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000108bd2e2d __33-[DVTFilePath cachedValueForKey:]_block_invoke549 + 245
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9fcbd33f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9fcbe926 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 74
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000108cd1005 DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 62
8   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000108a69627 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 116
9   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000108a715b0 -[DVTFilePath cachedValueForKey:] + 1802
10  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000108a70afc -[DVTToolchainRegistry scanSearchPathAndRegisterToolchains:] + 563
11  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001097d1a66 IDEInitialize + 655
12  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000109ecdf7c -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 708
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa18fa70c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa18fa67f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa18f9d47 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa18f9ab2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa18f3d42 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa17e2145 _CFXNotificationPost + 693
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9ef36921 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
20  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000108c6cf55 -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 698
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9db412c2 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 354
22  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000109275f62 -[DVTApplication finishLaunching] + 149
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9db40e05 -[NSApplication run] + 231
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9dac3520 NSApplicationMain + 1176
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9a8605ad start + 1
```

Could this be an issue due to Permissions conflicts?

ANSWER:

After I changed the rights from my OSX-Drive to everyone can write&read. Everything worked. But I knew that this is a temporary solution, so I decided to reinstall my MAC and everything was fine.

Comment: Please post your "ANSWER" section as an Answer, not added to the bottom of your Question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` by running this command in terminal:

```
rm -r ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData
```

If that doesnt work, At this point and with given info, all I could recommend to delete and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Is your OS up to date, is a real (not virtual) machine, have enough free hard drive space and meet the minimum requirements to run xcode?

Comment: Yes to all questions :)
Xcode ran 3 months without problems.

Comment: Also, delete ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState

Comment: Can you open xcode without opening your project? maybe your project is corrupted.... (can you open another project ?) or start a new project maybe

Comment: No I can't, I will try to open it after the reinstall of Xcode is finished. 2 GB left. Thank you for your help!

Comment: it still doenst work, can this cohere with my Problem that the spotlight cant find some applications like the Terminal and Xcode?

Comment: it sounds like its not even installed. if you want, i can remote desktop into you and have a look. my email is jeremie.jeremie at gmail.com if you want to get in touch.

Comment: Hello!

Thank you for your awesome help!

I just reinstalled my mac and then restored from Time Machine and all is working fine. The answer: something was wrong with user rights of my mac

Comment: Is there nothing that can't be solved by deleting derived data?! Thank you

Answer (score 31):

If the delete of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData is not working for you, try this steps to remove xcuserdata:

- open a Finder window and navigate to your project
- right-click on the .xcodeproj OR .xcworkspace file
- select Show Package Contents
- a new window appears
- delete a folder called xcuserdata

Comment: This is the first thing one should try in case of Xcode launch failure.

Comment: Added breakpoint. Xcode broken. Delete breakpoint data in xcuserdata folder. Xcode fixed. Am I misunderstanding breakpoints?

Comment: This only worked for me when I deleted the folder from both "xcodeproj" and "xcworkspace", like @Sunil Targe said.

Answer (score 1):

I had one where i selected a file that was quite large which crashed xcode when it tried to parse it. Then when i restarted it somehow it got set to load that file on start.  Only way i saw was to temporarily rename the file that it was trying to load at start so it would load empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend deleting `xcuserdata:` folder from both of your `.xcodeproj` & `.xcworkspace` file (open with Show Package Contents) and try again.

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure there are no issues with your SPM packages/dependencies.

This is simply another suggestion.  I just spent some time debugging this on a fairly popular open source project.

My Xcode first crashed when I updated a SPM package, so I was fairly certain it was an issue with one of the future commits in that package or a SPM bug.  I subscribe to Occam's Razor, so I started going through the changes in the commits.

After some time, I found a duplicate Swift Playground page delcaration in contents.xcplayground.  I removed that single line, pushed the PR, and everything worked fine after that.

To be able to reopen the project:

1. Open `project.pbxproj` in your code editor of choice (e.g. vi, nano, emacs, atom, code).
2. Remove the offending package or packages from the `/* Begin XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */` and `/* Begin XCSwiftPackageProductDependency section */` sections.
3. Save the file and Xcode should now open.

Again, if your Xcode is immediately crashing when opening a project (and you last updated/auto-updated a SPM package) go through your packages.